# Entity Framework Core 7 JSON Column - use a Dictionary<int, Object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In playing with EF Core 7 JSON Column I'm attempting to get to a point where my saved JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "Courses": [
        "123": {
            "RemoteCourseId": 123,
            "Delivery": {
                "Method": "email",
                "ModeTarget": "email@example.org",
                "Time": "13:30:00"
            },
            "Quizzes": [
                "54321": {
                    "RemoteQuizId": 54321,
                    "Credits": null,
                    "Details": {
                        "CompletedDate": null,
                        "StartDate": "2023-04-17T17:17:10.315684Z"
                    },
                    "Questions": [
                        "12345": {
                            "ExpirationDate": "2023-04-17T17:17:10.316138Z",
                            "IsCorrect": false,
                            "QuestionId": 12345,
                            "QuestionUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com",
                            "SentDate": "2023-04-17T17:17:10.316181Z"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The challenge I'm facing is how to get identifiers, shown another way:

```
{
    "Courses": [
        "123": {},
        "789": {}
    ]
}
```

I would like to get to a point where I can specify the "123" and "789".  My attempt at this is using a `Dictionary` like so:

```
public class LearnerCustomDataEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int LtiUserId { get; set; }

        public LearnerCustomDataDto Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class LearnerCustomDataDto
    {
        public LearnerCustomDataProfileDto Profile { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, LearnerCustomDataCourseDto> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

Within the DbContext I specify the JSON Column (`LearnerCustomDataEntity.Data`) like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LearnerCustomDataEntity>()
                .OwnsOne(l => l.Data, onb =>
                {
                    onb.OwnsOne<LearnerCustomDataProfileDto>(lcde => lcde.Profile);
                    onb.OwnsOne(lcdc => lcdc.Courses, onb =>
                    {
                        // I'm not sure _how_ to configure this
                        onb.HasOne(l => l);
                    });
                    onb.ToJson();
                });
```

I don't know how to configure the OwnedNavigationBuilder for the `LearnerCustomDataDto.Courses` field.

My end goal is to be able to get a specific course using something like

```
LearnerCustomDataCourseDto dto = dbContext.LearnerCustomData.Single(l => l.Data.Courses[123]);
```

Is using a dictionary the correct approach here? I'm certainly open to suggestions on doing it with a dictionary or changing to something else.

Update: I've tried using a KeyedCollection implementation as it would accomplish the goal of accessing via the key, but I'm having an issue with the conversion.  So, for example:

```
public class LearnerCustomDataDto
{
    public LearnerCustomDataProfileDto Profile { get; set; }

    public LearnerCustomDataCourseDtoCollection Courses { get; set; }
}

public class LearnerCustomDataCourseDtoCollection : KeyedCollection<int, LearnerCustomDataCourseDto>
{
    protected override int GetKeyForItem(LearnerCustomDataCourseDto item)
    {
        return item.RemoteCourseId;
    }
}
```

The updates to the context make it look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LearnerCustomDataEntity>()
                .OwnsOne(l => l.Data, onb =>
                {
                    onb.OwnsOne(lcde => lcde.Profile);
                    onb.OwnsMany(lcde => lcde.Courses);
                    onb.ToJson();
                });
```

However, when trying to delete an entity I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The requested operation requires an element of type 'Array', but the target element has type 'Object'.
Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.97]            at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonElementWrongTypeException(JsonTokenType expectedType, JsonTokenType actualType)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.EnumerateArray()
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.IncludeJsonEntityCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedCollectionElement](QueryContext queryContext, Nullable`1 jsonElement, Object[] keyPropertyValues, TIncludingEntity entity, Func`4 innerShaper, Action`2 fixup)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at lambda_method654(Closure, QueryContext, Object[], JsonElement)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at lambda_method653(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at lambda_method670(Closure, QueryContext)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
[xUnit.net 00:00:46.98]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
```

Which is triggered by:

```
_db.LearnerCustomData.SingleOrDefault(l => l.LtiUserId == defaultUser.Id);
```

Comment: Tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29825

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to just separate EF navigation property from JSON dictionary. Its a simple trick that should work with every ORM and every Serializer.

```cs
class ParentEntity
{
   [JsonIgnore]
   [XmlIgnore] [CsvIgnore] [FaxToCIAIgnore] //future proofing!
   public HashSet<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }

   [NotMapped] //don't include this field in EF black magic
   public Dictionary<int, ChildEntity> JsonChildren => Children.ToDictionary(c=>c.Id, c=>c);
}
```

Just add some attributes for nice property names and done.

But you should define `ViewModel`/`DTO` classes anyway, you'll still have `ToDictionary` either in query materialization or in getter property but won't get trout slapped during code review.

Your end goal just looks like selecting entity by two ID's, so just make simple select statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this - I don't want to ignore the fields, I want to take advantage of the new Json column features in EF7

Comment: @ChrisRockwell were you able to solve it? I have the same need